# Using reflection to pass a class as input

Tags: c#, class, reflection, quartz-scheduler

I have a function that creates a Quartz job and returns the scheduler as follows:

```
public IScheduler ScheduleJob<T>(string jobName, string jobGroup, string triggerName, string triggerGroup, bool rerun, string cronSchedule = "default", string startTime = "default") where T : IJob
    {
        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobGroup);
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<T>()
                .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                .StoreDurably()
                .Build();
        var trigger = cronSchedule != "default" ? QuartzCreateCronTrigger(triggerName, triggerGroup, cronSchedule, rerun, startTime) : QuartzCreateTrigger(triggerName, triggerGroup);

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        return scheduler;
    }
```

I have several classes, each of which contains a job to be scheduled and run. I have the following function that takes the name of one of those classes and some additional information, then schedules the job. This function calls the above function.

```
public static void CreateScheduler(bool rerun, string jobName, string jobType, string schedule, string startTime)
{
    var job =  (IJob) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyProject.Jobs." + jobType + "." + jobName + ", " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.ToString()));
    var scheduler =
        new QuartzConstraints().ScheduleJob<job>(
            jobName,
            jobType,
            jobName + "Trigger",
            jobType,
            rerun,
            schedule,
            startTime);
    scheduler.Start();
}
```

The problem is that I get an error in `new QuartzConstraints().ScheduleJob<job>(...)`, saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'job'". `ScheduleJob<T>` should have `T` as type `IJob`, which is correct. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Edit:

The code works when I define each class specifically, but I want to write a method (`CreateScheduler`) generalized to work for any class. For instance, this works (where `ThisIsAJobClass` is a class that implements `IJob`):

```
 var scheduler =
     new QuartzConstraints().ScheduleJob<ThisIsAJobClass>(
        "ThisIsAJobClass",
        "JobGroup1",
        "ThisIsAJobClassTrigger",
        "JobGroup1",
        true,
        "0 0/1 * ? * MON-FRI",
        "6:20 AM");
scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: What is the point of declaring `var job` in your `CreateScheduler` method? It's not used anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in `ScheduleJob<job>` to pass the class to the method `ScheduleJob`.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `new QuartzConstrainst().ScheduleJob<IJob>`, not `.ScheduleJob<job>`.

`job` isn't a type, and you said yourself that `ScheduleJob<T> should have T as type IJob`.

If you want to pass your `var job` to `ScheduleJob`, then you should define `SheduleJob` like so:

```
public IScheduler ScheduleJob<T>(
    T job, // <-- add this
    string jobName,
    string jobGroup,
    string triggerName,
    string triggerGroup,
    bool rerun,
    string cronSchedule = "default",
    string startTime = "default") where T : IJob
{
    // code
}
```

and then pass `job` to this function like so:

```
public static void CreateScheduler(bool rerun, string jobName, string jobType, string schedule, string startTime)
{
    var job =  (IJob) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyProject.Jobs." + jobType + "." + jobName + ", " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.ToString()));
    var scheduler =
        new QuartzConstraints().ScheduleJob<IJob>(
            job // <-- add this
            jobName,
            jobType,
            jobName + "Trigger",
            jobType,
            rerun,
            schedule,
            startTime);
    scheduler.Start();
}
```

Comment: `job` has type `IJob`. I'm trying to pass the class with name `jobName` to `ScheduleJob<class goes here>`. I thought I could do it through reflection, which is what I thought I was doing above. Is there another way?

Comment: I saw your edit. What is the point of adding `T job`? It will never be used in the code for `ScheduleJob`, since I cannot replace the line `JobBuilder.Create<T>()...` with `JobBuilder.Create<job>()...`

Comment: Furthermore, using `ScheduleJob<IJob>` gives the error that `Probem instantiating class 'Quartz.IJob' ---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor. Parameter name: IJob`